# How to add a word to the line below using regular expression in python?

Tags: python, expression

I need a regular expression in python to add {\an8} in the start of every line below the lines contains 'line:10.00%' , thanks.

Comment: The source of the file is a subtitle file in WEBvtt format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this and let me know if it worked

```
import re
re.sub('line[^\n]*(\n*)([\w\W])', r'\1an8\2', your_string)
```

Comment: `re.sub('line[^\n]*(\n*)([\w\W])', r'\1an8\2', your_string)` alright this is a generic one for the word "line" in the previous string.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the inputs in a String-

```
s =  "00:01:54.208 --> 00:01:57.166 position:50.00%,middle align:middle size:80.00% line:10.00%"

find = 'line:10.00%'
s1 = r"{\an8}"
if find in s:
    s = s1+" "+s
    print(s)

Out: {\an8} 00:01:54.208 --> 00:01:57.166 position:50.00%,middle align:middle size:80.00% line:10.00%
```

Answer (score 1):

This one iterates through lines checking the status of current line, i.e if it contains the phrase to be checked, set a flag if so and update the next line:

```
s = '''00:01:54.208 --> 00:01:57.166 position:50.00%,middle align:middle size:80.00% line:10.00% 

Gonna let you down'''

flag, lines = 0, s.split('\n')

for x, line in enumerate(lines):
    if flag and line:
        lines[x] = '{\\an8}' + line
        flag = 0
    if 'line:10.00%' in line:
        flag = 1

print('\n'.join(lines))

# 00:01:54.208 --> 00:01:57.166 position:50.00%,middle align:middle size:80.00% line:10.00%
# 
# {\an8}Gonna let you down
```

Comment: Can `line:10.00%` come anywhere in a line or only at the end?